# Bone shrinks mysteriously under the influence of an IK Constraint

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

I tried setting up inverse kinematics on a very simple test character rig and the bone went all crazy. It shrinks the leg to a stump when the IK Constraint's influence is at 1. I've set it to 0.5 so you can see what's happening, and still select it. It also can't be grabbed.

[image: Bone shrinks mysteriously under the influence of an IK Constraint]

My experience with rigging is limited, but still it's surprising to see this bizarre result. Please explain to me what's causing this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Family Problems

The scaling problem was because bone's IK Target was itself. (D'oh!) That caused it to implode.

I guess the only way it can point more at itself is to shrink into oblivion.

**The IK Target should be an unrelated bone.** Usually one having its root located at the tip of the bone with the IK Constraint. By "unrelated" I mean it should not be a parent or a child of the IK-constrained bone.

From what I have observed, it shouldn't be related to *any* of the bones in the chain, actually. I believe this means that if you want the target bone to follow along with the armature properly you need to have a bone it copies its location from, using a Bone Constraint. Remember it like this: "No targeting your own family".

Also, there are two types of targets in IK: An *IK Target*, and an *IK Pole Target*. The terminology had me mixed up. **The *IK Target* is the bone the tip of the IK-constrained bone will point at, and the *IK Pole Target* is the bone that the chain will bend toward (like a knee).**

When adding an IK Constraint, first select the bone that will be the IK Target, and then Shift-select the bone that will be constrained. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> and add it to the Active Bone.

Here's a simple example setup:

[image: Simple inverse kinematics setup]

### Additional Tips

- Remember to do Parenting/Unparenting in Edit Mode, and Bone Constraints in Pose Mode.
- Leave some bend in the knees in the direction of the IK Pole Target
- You may also have to rotate the Pole Angle in the settings of the IK Constraint. (I don't know why this is sometimes necessary and sometimes not.)

I think I've just overcome one of my biggest hurdles in rigging. Everyone, feel free to correct me or add something if my understanding is incomplete.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p0htATi5tpA) helped me to get it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the bone IK constraint, try to disable weight influence for position, leave it only for rotation. You can restore influence to 1.0 as is probably needed for rotation.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that solves the scaling problem - however since I also can't grab and re-position the bone it's useless as a bone. Do you know what's causing this? It's very strange behavior.