# Apply scale on animated character goes wrong

Tags: animation, transforms

So I have an animated character that needs to be scaled up (For our game engine). However when I apply the scale to the armature(ctrl+a), the arms which have an IK chain, mess up. 
As seen in the "scale-up apply" picture, the arms are 90 degrees instead of the animated angle. Is there a trick to fix this? Or does it come down to adjusting the animations.

Initial scale-up:
[image]

Scale-up apply:
[image]

Comment: One more thing to make clear - did you try follow instructions like in [this thread](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?267916-How-to-Scale-Rigged-Character-Problems-can-anyone-help), like using a group and empty ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that option. The initial scaling goes fine, however when I apply the scale it messes up.

Comment: I had a problem before with bone scale relating to IK. [Here's the link](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43189/bone-shrinks-mysteriously-under-the-influence-of-an-ik-constraint/43350#43350) in case it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Mentalist , The rig should be fine "I guess", I have some experience with IK and made sure the "helper/bone" wasn't parented.