# IK doesn't move the whole leg Parenting Loop Error

Tags: rigging, bones

I got stuck on my IK bone. It suppose to move the whole leg, however only foot moves. Here is the screenshot.Parenting works, but gives me "parent loop error". Any other solutions? [image]

Comment: Select the IK target bone and press Alt P to Clear Parent.

Comment: I struggled with understanding this at first too. [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43350) might help you.